# Как сделать разделение через точку в больших числах? C# unity

Tags: c#, unity3d

Есть кликер, чтобы глазам было удобнее хочу сделать визуально разделение в больших числах.
Например:
Не 10000, а 10.000
Не 1000000, а 1.000.000

Понимаю, что сначала надо числа преобразовать в строку, отсчитать нужное количество символов и вставить точку. Но на практике сделать так не получается, мало опыта(

Если не составит труда, было бы очень хорошо рассмотреть примерную реализацию в коде

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3457032/8324991